# error: could not load android-info.txt

Tags: android, build, porting, android-source, fastboot

After I built the source code of android, I ran the following command and got the error.

```
#fastboot -w flashall
error: could not load android-info.txt
```

I had successfully built the source code for nexus one (build 5), and I found that there is a android-info.txt file in the directory out/target/passion/.

Also, I am sure that the phone is connected. When I run "fastboot devices", it shows the device.

Anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Old thread so sorry for reactivating it, but it's still one of the top hits and it's unanswered. 
My fix was to ensure I had the ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT environment variable, and that it was pointing to
 `/home/{usr name}/{build directory}/out/target/product/{taget}`

Again, sorry for resurrecting a dead post.

Answer (score 1):

As `$fastboot flashall -w`

flash the Rom on connected device it needs to know which `Run/Device/Product` you want to flash as there might be many products available in `out/target/product` directory,
And so product is obtained by `ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT` variable which should point to any product i.e.

```
/home/{usr name}/{build directory}/out/target/product/{taget}
```

And to set the `ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT` we just need to do:

```
source build/envsetup.sh 
lunch
```

and choose your product in lunch menu, so that `fastboot flashall -w`  would know which product you wanna flash.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the flash all script is organized. Try flashing into the partition directly.

Eg: fastboot flash system system.img

I observed this issue when trying to fastboot update an OTA package.

Eg: fastboot update xyz.zip.

Currect way to update via fastboot is

fastboot update updateImagename.img

Answer (score 0):

Call lunch to set the environment variables needed.
For example,
'lunch aosp_flo-eng' can be called to make sure the environment is in order for the Nexus 7 [2013] tablet.